# How to test the onClick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I'm new to JS and I have a scenario like this. Clicking on the button will bring up a `div` content (written in jQuery).

Now say I want to test the scenario, how should I do this? People prefer Jasmine.

But I wonder, how that make sense, because if we test like this:

```
Test: emulate click on button and check the div content is visible.
```

If we follow this *pattern* aren't we testing the `onClick` of the jquery and not testing our behaviour?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually testing the `click` event of jQuery though *per-se*, you're testing the **process of showing a `div` on click of another `button`**, which includes testing that:

- Your `div` is on the page
- jQuery has loaded correctly
- Your `div` has the appropriate ID
- Your `div` that you want to show is in the DOM
- Your `div` that you want to show and does actually get shown

Comment: But still, if thats all going to happen in `onClick` method, then its jquery responsibility to call them right? I'm not getting the idea behind Jasmine.

Comment: @batman Well technically no, it's not jQuery's responsibility to make sure the element exists in the DOM with the appropriate ID (that's your responsibility)

Comment: @batman Jasmin is for behaviour driven development testing, so it's difficult to give you the idea without knowing your development scenario. I'd consider reading up on Behaviour Driven Development to better understand the techniques used with Jasmine